# Pattern to extract value in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have various strings that look like this:

```
Status-Active
Status-Inactive 10
```

I want to get only the status 'Active' and 'Inactive' without the space and number.

I tried with `(?<=-)\S+` and worked on a website, but doing it the same in Java can't find anything.

```
private final Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("(?<=-)\\S+");
...
Matcher m = reg.matcher(status);
if(m.matches())
    status = m.group(0);
```

Comment: I'd try something like `((?:In)?[Aa]ctive)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you have a pattern that is as close to the matched string as possible.

```
Pattern patter = Pattern.compile("Status-(Active|Inactive)");
```

And then use group 1 to find the status string.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use regex in your case, instead:

```
status = line.contains("Inactive")?"Inactive":"Active";
```

Comment: That seems pretty fragile to me. If the input changes for any reason it'll silently assume the new input means 'active'. The advantage of the regular expression is that it is an implicit assertion that the input is correct.

Comment: @sprinter Good point. Yes, it would break when there should be other statuses than these two. Otherwise, this ad hoc solution works and looks simpler.